# Custom Category Type in Opencart

Tags: opencart, categories

I'm working in an online book store and I faced 2 problems with opencart.

1 - I would like to use some kind relevance in the order of the categories listed, for exemple:
*- this book is about theme 1  // but it also contains some minor content from theme 2 and theme 3.*

So in the frontend it would look like:

Main Area: Theme 1
Related Areas: Theme 2, Theme 3


2 - The other problem involves the authors. Most of the books are collections of works from various authors. So, one specific author could be in various books. I want the authors to behave like categories, so when the customer clicked in the name, it would show all the books from that author.

In Wordpress that would be really easy to do with Custom Post Types and Custom Taxonomy, but in Opencart I just can't find where to edit to get those modifications. (Wordpress is not an option because the client wants Opencart)

Is this possible to do?

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Can you give a  little bit more detail on what you are doing? for Authors you can use,Models

Comment: Thanks for the attention, but I solved this using php. They are all categories in the backend, but in the front-end I test using the parent_id.